# InfoPath-Place text box on an image

Tags: infopath, image

I have a requirement on my forms to have a sort of helpful hint text box that will change it's text when someone clicks on a button.  The issue I'm having is that they have a specific "speech bubble" image they want used.  My question is, can I place a text box on top of an image?  My goal would then be to remove the borders, making the image itself appear interactive.

Thank you!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can do it, either we can add a screen tip for the image control field.

OR

We can create a small table with the 2 cells 1. Image control 2. section and inside that a textbox.

Write a rule on **Image** Control field - and as an action select **set field value** - there set the text for the textbox which is there inside the section.

Example:

[image: Text changes based on the image button click.PNG]

In the above example, when image button is clicked - then the corresponding text will appear in the textbox.

Note:

- By default hide this section(text field) - show only when it has value - this can be controlled through the rule formatting.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What I'm trying to do is take an image from my desktop (speech bubble) and place a text box on top.  The layout for my form has maybe 8 fields with text boxes and drop downs.  I'm placing small buttons next to each field that the user can click on if they need clarification on what to enter in one of the fields.  This is where I'd like to write the rule to change the text in the speech bubble based on which button is clicked.  I think really my only other alternative is to just create a text box and try to make it look like the speech bubble.

Comment: In this case, you can create a textbox field which should be hidden by default and after each button click the value of the text box should be updated through the button action rule.